# My React master component cannot find the imported container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, components, react-component

**My APP.js file cannot get another component.**
I am trying to import MainComponent to the app.js component but it cannot fetch the component.
Please help me resolve this prooblem.

***The error***

```
ERROR in ./src/App.js 10:35-39
export 'Main' (imported as 'Main') was not found in './myComponents/mainComponent' (possible exports: default)
```

**Here is my Main Component.**

```
import React from 'react';
import ContentThree from './d53-content';

 function Main(){
  
    return (
      <div>
          < Header />
          <div className="container">
             <div className='col-12 col-md-4'></div>
             </div>
          </div>
         </Header>
      </div>
    );
}
export default Main;
```

**Here is my app.js file***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Main } from './myComponents/mainComponent';


function App(){
  
    return (
            <div>
              < Main />
            </div>
    ); 
}

export default (App);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use

```
import Main from './myComponents/mainComponent';
```

instead of

```
import { Main } from './myComponents/mainComponent';
```

**Reason**: You are exporting the default component using `export default Main` which means it's a single component you are exporting. SO you need to export it directly instead of seperating it.

But still, if you want to use like `import {Main} '../location_of_file'` then you need to export it like

```
export function Main(props){
// code
}
```

*And also check your Header tab. You are closing it already and then why you are using  to close it.*

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
```

import ContentThree from './d53-content';

function Main(){

```
return (
  <div>
      < Header /> --- 1
      <div className="container">
         <div className='col-12 col-md-4'></div>
         </div>
      </div>
     </Header> -- 2
  </div>
);
```

}
export default Main;

1. here above in header component the first tag is self closed.
2. and here this is a closing tag
   change the first one to just and opening tag like 
   or remove the second closing tag